# EclipseLink Mongodb CriteriaQuery on @Embedded field

Tags: mongodb, jpa, nosql

I am trying to use CriteriaQuery with Eclipselink 2.5.2 and MongoDb. I have the following classes:

User:

```java
@Entity
@NoSql(dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Field(name="_id")
    private String id;

    @Field(name="USERID")
    private String userId;

    @Field(name="fullName")
    private String fullName;

    @Field(name="AGE")
    private String age;

    @Field(name="STATUS")
    private String status;

    @Embedded
    @Field(name="address")
    private Address address = new Address();

    ...Getters/Setters
}
```

Address:

```java
@Embeddable
@NoSql(dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
public class Address {
    @Field(name="addressId")
    private String addressId = "";

    @Field(name="@addressValue")
    private String addressValue = "";

    ...Getters/Setters
}
```

When I run the following CriteriaQuery:

```java
// Criteria
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> query = cb.createQuery(User.class);
// From
Root<User> from = query.from(User.class);
// Filter
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

predicates.add(cb.equal(from.get("address").get("addressValue"), "1234 Main St"));
Predicate[] preds = null;
preds = predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
query.where(preds);
```

I get the following error:

> Criteria expression is of primitive type and can not be further
>   navigated.

However if u run a JPQL query it works just fine.

```java
em.createQuery("Select u from User u where u.address.addressValue = :address")
  .setParameter("address", "1234 Main St")
  .setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
```

Is there something special I need to do in order to query on fields in the Embedded object? If I just filter on User things are find in CriteriaQuery.

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but why not just call query.where(cb.equal(from.get("address").get("addressValue"), "1234 Main St")) ?

Comment: I just did the same query via Criteria (across 1-1 embedded relation) with DataNucleus JPA and MongoDB and it executed that query fine (using either the hardcoded literal value or a parameter), executing Mongo DB.find() behind the scenes with a filter of {"address.addressValue" : "1234 Main St"}

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: the below answer it's **not** a solution, rather a detailed explanation why it's not working currently.

I have reproduced the problem with EclipseLink 2.5.2 and MongoDB. A few conclusions:

- looks like an embedded field mapped to NoSQL data is not supported for MongoDB
- in order to get a satisfactory solution it may be necessary to [create a bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)
- I am not sure how it behaves with other NoSQL databases since I had no opportunity to cross-check any of them
- the problem may be related to all NoSQL adapters leveraging `EISCompositeObjectMapping` class (more on this below)

As a **temporary workaround** consider replacing `Address` embeddable by placing its field directly in the `User` entity.

---

Here's what I have found - setting up `eclipselink.logging.metamodel` level to FINEST in persistence.xml

```xml
<properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoPlatform"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.nosql.connection-spec" value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoConnectionSpec"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.port" value="27017"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.db" value="odm_eclipselink"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.metamodel" value="FINEST"/>
</properties>
```

shows the following output for EclipseLink + MongoDB:

```
[EL Finest]: metamodel: 2015-05-12 20:33:48.906--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Metamodel processing: The mapping type [org.eclipse.persistence.eis.mappings.EISCompositeObjectMapping[address]] in the attribute [SingularAttributeImpl[null,org.eclipse.persistence.eis.mappings.EISCompositeObjectMapping[address]]] is currently unsupported.
[EL Finest]: metamodel: 2015-05-12 20:33:48.906--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Metamodel processing: The class type is null for the attribute: SingularAttributeImpl[null,org.eclipse.persistence.eis.mappings.EISCompositeObjectMapping[address]].
[EL Finer]: metamodel: 2015-05-12 20:33:48.906--ServerSession(13500464)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Canonical Metamodel class [eclipselink.User_] found and instantiated during initialization.
[EL Finer]: metamodel: 2015-05-12 20:33:48.906--ServerSession(13500464)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Canonical Metamodel class [eclipselink.Address_] found and instantiated during initialization.
```

The above output clearly states that the feature is currently unsupported (well, at least from end-user's point of view).

From the static metamodel point of view `User.Address` embedded attribute is represented by `SingularAttribute<User, Address>`. Going deeper we can figure out that `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl` instantiates `SingularAttributeImpl<EntityTypeImpl<User>, BasicTypeImpl<Object>>` 
with help of `EISCompositeObjectMapping` class which defines how an attribute (address=embeddable) is aggregated and structured in relation to its parent (user=enity). 
Now, the root-cause of the problem is the most likely lack of a proper mapping as shown on the `org.eclipse.persistence.mappings` class hierarchy below:

```
CoreMapping
     |
DatabaseMapping
     |
AggregateMapping
     |
AbstractCompositeObjectMapping  | @Override
     |                          | public Class getAttributeClassification() {
EISCompositeObjectMapping ------|     return null; // root-cause of the problem!
                                | }    
                                |
```

Lack of implementation in `getAttributeClassification()` method leads to *unsupported mapping* in metamodel log and instantiation of `BasicTypeImpl` (rather than `EmbeddableTypeImpl`) which is wrong in this particular case.

---

For comparison, the same scenario for EclipseLink + PostgreSQL works like a charm:

```
[EL Finer]: metamodel: Canonical Metamodel class [com.wypieprz.jpa.example.model.Address_] found and instantiated during initialization.
[EL Finer]: metamodel: Canonical Metamodel class [com.wypieprz.jpa.example.model.User_] found and instantiated during initialization.
```

The important difference is under the hood as `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider` which is related to SQL databases uses different mapping class in comparison
with MongoDB case. This time the metamodel implementation instantiates `SingularAttributeImpl<EntityTypeImpl<User>, EmbeddableTypeImpl<Object>>` 
with help of `AggregateObjectMapping` class whose implementation works as expected:

```
CoreMapping
     |
DatabaseMapping
     |
AggregateMappping            | @Override
     |                       | public Class getAttributeClassification() {
AggregateObjectMapping ------|     return getReferenceClass();
                             | }
                             |
```

This time `getAttributeClassification()` method leads to *found and instantiated* in metamodel log and instantiation of `EmbeddableTypeImpl` which is expected.